# How to log kernel messages to /var/log/messages on Yocto system with systemd?

Tags: yocto, systemd-journald

We have a fairly standard Yocto system with Busybox and systemd. We have noticed that kernel messages (visible with dmesg etc) are not logged to /var/log/messages, but are only visible with "journalctl".

The system runs all of these:

```
/sbin/klogd -n
/sbin/syslogd -n
/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
```

I have noticed that kernel messages are actually logged in /var/log/messages if journald is stopped. That service provides little of value to us, so disabling or removing it altogether could be a solution, but how can this be done?